# Retrieving emails from a Catch-all email address

Tags: catch-all

I migrated an entire email system for my own domain from GMail to another provider, still using my domain name. In the new system, not all email addresses from the original GMail system were recreated. I set up a Catch-all email and it is working well.

After about a week, I then recreated in the new system some more email addresses that were in the GMail system originally. These email addresses are missing the emails sent to them during the one week period and all these missing emails are sitting in the Catch-all mailbox to which I have web, IMAP and POP3 access.

How can I extract the missing emails from the Catch-all mailbox and copy or forward them to the original mailboxes they were intended for? I want an automated process using a program in which I feed the target email address and any other relevant parameters.

I do not have root access in the new system. I have the same kind of access as in the Google for your domain admin panel.

Thanks.

Comment: You should state this question on Super User, not Stack Overflow

Comment: Is that another website? What's the URL? I have seen questions on this site about Catch-all mailboxes.

Comment: Its another stack exchange site